# make collapsible custom task panes in outlook?

Tags: vsto, add-in, outlook-addin

Is it possible to make collapsible task panes in outlook. ie. Can I have a button on lets say a ribbon that upon clicking can either make the pane appear, or if it is already open make is collapse or disappear? Everything I've been able to find related to this involves add-in express, which I do not have. Any help or leads would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add-In Express is not required to show or hide a custom task pane. You can toggle the **Custom Task Pane** visibility by using the [`TaskPane.Visible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpane.visible.aspx) property.

```
customTaskPane.Visible = false; // hides task pane from view
```

See [**Custom Task Panes** on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864.aspx) for further reference, specifically the section "*Modifying the Appearance of the Task Pane*"